# Choose dictionary keys only if their values don't have a certain number of duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary and a limit for the number of keys in a new dictionary, I would like the new dictionary to contain the keys with the highest values.

The given dict is:

```
dict = {'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1 }
```

I want to get a new dictionary that has the keys with the highest values of length limit.

For instance for limit=1 the new dict is

```
{'apple':5}
```

if the limit=2

```
{'apple':5, 'pears':4}
```

I tried this:

```
return dict(sorted(dictation.items(),key=lambda x: -x[1])[:limit])
```

but when I try limit=3, I get

```
{'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3}
```

But it shouldn't include orange:3 **because orange and kiwi have same priority** if we include kiwi and orange it will exceed the limit so it shouldn't include both. I should return

```
{'apple':5, 'pears':4}
```

Comment: I followed this question until you said "because I can't add orange. If I add it will be more than the limit.".

Comment: So you're saying if there are multiple items with the same count, you should only take any if all of them fit within the limit? Have you looked into whether `Counter.most_common` does what you need? I'd recommend not trying to fit it into one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go would be to use a `collections.Counter` and `most_common(n)`. Then you can take one more as needed and keep popping until the last value changes:

```
from collections import Counter

dct = {'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}
n = 3

items = Counter(dictation).most_common(n+1)
last_val = items[-1][1]
if len(items) > n:
    while items[-1][1] == last_val:
        items.pop()

new = dict(items)
# {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}
```

Comment: But OP says for `limit=3` the dict should still have 2 keys, for reasons I don't unterstand.

Comment: @timgeb I added the necessary bumpiness. Lost all of its appeal :(

Comment: still shorter then mine

Answer (score 1):

This is computationally not very good, but it works. It creates a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object to get the sorted output for your data and a inverted [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that holds list that match to a score - it creates the result using both and some math:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def gimme(d,n):
    c = Counter(d)
    grpd = defaultdict(list)
    for key,value in c.items():
        grpd[value].append(key)


    result = {}
    for key,value in c.most_common():
        if len(grpd[value])+len(result) <= n:
            result.update( {k:value for k in grpd[value] } )
        else:
            break
    return result
```

Test:

```
data = {'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1 }

for k in range(10):
    print(k, gimme(data,k))
```

Output:

```
0 {}
1 {'apple': 5}
2 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}
3 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}
4 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3, 'kiwi': 3}
5 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3, 'kiwi': 3}
6 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3, 'kiwi': 3, 'banana': 1}
7 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3, 'kiwi': 3, 'banana': 1}
8 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3, 'kiwi': 3, 'banana': 1}
9 {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3, 'kiwi': 3, 'banana': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you note, filtering by the top *n* doesn't exclude by default all equal values which exceed the stated cap. This is by design.

The trick is to consider the *(n+1)* th highest value and ensure the values in your dictionary are all higher than this number:

```
from heapq import nlargest

dictation = {'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}

n = 3
largest_items = nlargest(n+1, dictation.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
n_plus_one_value = largest_items[-1][1]

res = {k: v for k, v in largest_items if v > n_plus_one_value}

print(res)

{'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}
```

We assume here `len(largest_items) < n`, otherwise you can just take the input dictionary as the result.

---

The dictionary comprehension seems expensive. For larger inputs, you can use `bisect`, something like:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter
from bisect import bisect

dictation = {'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}

n = 3
largest_items = nlargest(n+1, dictation.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
n_plus_one_value = largest_items[-1][1]

index = bisect(list(map(itemgetter(1), largest_items))[::-1], n_plus_one_value)

res = dict(largest_items[:len(largest_items) - index])

print(res)

{'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}
```